# Why does onnxruntime fail to create CUDAExecutionProvider in Linux(Ubuntu 20)?

Tags: python, onnxruntime

```
import onnxruntime as rt
ort_session = rt.InferenceSession(
            "my_model.onnx",
            providers=["CUDAExecutionProvider"],
)
```

onnxruntime (onnxruntime-gpu 1.13.1) works (in Jupyter VsCode env - Python 3.8.15) well when *providers* is `["CPUExecutionProvider"]`. But for `["CUDAExecutionProvider"]` it sometimes(not always) throws an error as:

```
[W:onnxruntime:Default, onnxruntime_pybind_state.cc:578 CreateExecutionProviderInstance] Failed to create CUDAExecutionProvider. Please reference https://onnxruntime.ai/docs/reference/execution-providers/CUDA-ExecutionProvider.html#requirements to ensure all dependencies are met.
```

I tried following the provided link in the error, and tried different setups in the conda environment to test the code with various version combinations.

Answer (score 11):

Replacing:

```
import onnxruntime as rt
```

with

```
import torch
import onnxruntime as rt
```

somehow perfectly solved my problem.

Comment: The reason might be related to the fact that requirements include *CUDA* and *cuDNN* and these are installed within *pytorch* in *conda*. Importing torch would be enabling CUDA/cuDNN in the kernel.

Comment: Because pytorch contains all cuda libraries. When you import pytorch, it also imports cuda libraries in memory.

Answer (score 2):

In my case the following helped:

1. uninstall `onnxruntime`
2. uninstall `onnxruntime-gpu`
3. install `optimum[onnxruntime-gpu]`

more [here](https://huggingface.co/docs/optimum/main/en/onnxruntime/usage_guides/gpu#installation)

Answer (score 1):

1. You should check your onnxruntime-gpu version ,cuda version and cudnn version in this link 'https://onnxruntime.ai/docs/execution-providers/CUDA-ExecutionProvider.html'
2. Use 'nvcc -V' and 'cat /usr/local/cuda/include/cudnn_version.h' make sure your env is useful.
3. 'import torch' is necessary,the code as is follows:

- import torch
- import onnxruntime as rt
- providers = ['CUDAExecutionProvider', 'CPUExecutionProvider']
- session = rt.InferenceSession("yolo.onnx", providers=providers)

Comment: For me the issue was that ONNX installation for CUDA 12 was slightly different. It didn't throw an error at install time, but just didn't work right. Thanks for the link: https://onnxruntime.ai/docs/execution-providers/CUDA-ExecutionProvider.html

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but with TensorRT `TensorrtExecutionProvider`:

```bash
[W:onnxruntime:Default, onnxruntime_pybind_state.cc:614 CreateExecutionProviderInstance] Failed to create TensorrtExecutionProvider. Please reference https://onnxruntime.ai/docs/execution-providers/TensorRT-ExecutionProvider.html#requirements to ensure all dependencies are met.
```

Look like in this case one have to import `tensorrt` and have to do so **before** importing `onnxruntime` (GPU):

```py
import tensorrt
import onnxruntime as ort

# Inference with ONNX TensorRT
```